# orchard cms create pages in cms

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have an Orchard CMS application. I want to create multiple pages in that other than the homepage. I want to display a menu on the other pages. When user logs in, the menu should be displayed according to his role. Can anybody give me solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new pages in the admin Dashboard by choosing **New --> Page** in admin menu.
Menu is static atm, so there's no out-of-the-box functionality to limit the menu items to the current user role(s). 
Btw - I'm building a module for this, though, so such a feature will be available in few weeks.

Cheers

Comment: Let's say I am a content publisher. How can I use live writer or ms word to publish pages. I can do this for blog post but not for pages. How to create page content type from a nice external tool like live writer?

Answer (score 0):

To add a menu to "other than homepage" - You can add a layer with rule !url'/homepage' (that might not be exact.)  Then you can assign a menu widget to that layer.

Now, getting a role based menu is a little tougher.  Can you use roles in the layer rules?  I haven't seen it but if it exists, you could create a layer for each role with the a rule like this.  !url'/homepage' && role'foo'